# Meteor - How can I see console.log in the server side?

Tags: meteor

I'm debugging a big open source project written by `meteor` (https://github.com/wekan/wekan).

I added some `console.log()` debug code, use `$ meteor` to run the project under the command line, but I can't see anything printed in the console nor in the browser F12.

I reached some similar questions but I can only find "it just works" or "it's in the browser console" answers. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Does the `console.log()` will just print the logs in my command line console?

Thank you!

Comment: console.log output will appear in the terminal that you ran the `meteor` command from. You can also use the VSCode debugger to attach to the server process, set breakpoints, inspect variables and step through the code

Comment: So there's something wrong so I don't see the log. Thank you!

Comment: @RomulusUrakagiTs'ai Make sure the part which contains you're console.logs are actually being invoked, and also if you want to print out those statements in the terminal you must place them in serverside. 

Here's a snippet to test logging:

```
        Meteor.startup(function () {
        if (Meteor.isServer){
                console.log('is server');
            }
        });
```